# Environ("Temp") returns old-style 8.3 values in Visual Basic

Tags: windows, vb.net, environment-variables, vb6

Busy writing unit tests in Visual Studio 2019 for some (rather old) Visual Basic 6 code that was recently ported to VB.NET.

Stumbled on the following:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Environ("TEMP")
' Returns "C:\\Users\\DANNY~1.LON\\AppData\\Local\\Temp%"

System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)
' Returns "C:\\Users\\Danny.LongName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp%"
```

Is there any control over how `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Environ` works? The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.environ?view=net-7.0) doesn't appear to say anything about this DOS-like 8.3 mangling.

Should the old VB6 `Interaction.Environ` be converted to the more modern `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`?

Comment: Depends on your needs but it sounds like you want the non-8.3 version so I'd say move on with `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`

Comment: If you're after a temp path, I'd suggest moving on to the more modern `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath`.

Comment: Does your application have any compatibility settings in the EXE?

Comment: @StayOnTarget: No, though it is an x86 application running on x64 Windows. Don't know if that's relevant.